# How to understand the output of tracing running an external command in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, exec, fork, strace

In Ubuntu, I run `date` directly in an interactive bash shell whose pid is 6913.

```
$ date
Wed Mar  2 23:57:44 EST 2016
```

At the same time, I trace the bash shell 6913 from another interactive bash shell using `strace`:

```
    $ sudo strace -f -e trace=process -p 6913
    Process 6913 attached
    clone(Process 9098 attached
    child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD,
    child_tidptr=0x7f457c05ca10) = 9098
    [pid  6913] wait4(-1,  <unfinished ...>
    [pid  9098] execve("/bin/date", ["date"], [/* 66 vars */]) = 0
    [pid  9098] arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7f40d6a4f740) = 0
    [pid  9098] exit_group(0)               = ?
    [pid  9098] +++ exited with 0 +++
    <... wait4 resumed> [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], WSTOPPED|WCONTINUED, NULL) = 9098
    --- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=9098, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
    wait4(-1, 0x7ffea6781518, WNOHANG|WSTOPPED|WCONTINUED, NULL) = -1 ECHILD (No child processes)
    clone(Process 9099 attached
    child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7f457c05ca10) = 9099
    [pid  9099] clone(Process 9100 attached
    child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7f457c05ca10) = 9100
    [pid  9099] wait4(-1,  <unfinished ...>
    [pid  9100] execve("/bin/sed", ["sed", "s:\\([^/]\\)[^/]*/:\\1/:g"], [/* 66 vars */]) = 0
    [pid  9100] arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7f998bb03840) = 0
    [pid  9100] exit_group(0)               = ?
    [pid  9100] +++ exited with 0 +++
    [pid  9099] <... wait4 resumed> [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], 0, NULL) = 9100
    [pid  9099] --- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=9100, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
    [pid  9099] wait4(-1, 0x7ffea6780c58, WNOHANG, NULL) = -1 ECHILD (No child processes)
    [pid  9099] exit_group(0)               = ?
    [pid  9099] +++ exited with 0 +++
    --- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=9099, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
    wait4(-1, [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], WNOHANG|WSTOPPED|WCONTINUED, NULL) = 9099
    wait4(-1, 0x7ffea6780f18, WNOHANG|WSTOPPED|WCONTINUED, NULL) = -1 ECHILD (No child processes)
```

It seems to me the output can be divided into two parts:

1. First the bash shell 6913  `clone()` itself to create a subprocess
       9098, and then the subprocess 9098 `execve()` `date` and exits.
2. After these, the bash shell 6913 `clone()` itself to create a
       subprocess 9099, then the subprocess 9099 `clone()` itself to create
       a subsubprocess 9100, and then the subsubprocess 9100 `execve()` `sed`. **My question** is about this second part:

   - Do the last two `clone()` and the last `execve()`  belong to the action that handles SIGCHLD received by the bash shell 6913? 
     What does the action do?
   - Why does process 9100 `execve()` `sed`? What does `sed` do here?
   - Why isn't process 9099 the process that `execve()` `sed`? Why does 9099 `clone()` to create 9100, and then 9100 `execve()` `sed`? In other words, why do we need two sequential clones 9099 and 9100, rather than just one clone 9099?

---

To answer the comment:

```
$ echo $PROMPT_COMMAND
pwd2=$(sed "s:\([^/]\)[^/]*/:\1/:g" <<<$PWD)
$ echo $PS1
\u@\h:$pwd2\$
```

After running `unset PROMPT_COMMAND` in shel 6913, the tracing output is

```
$ sudo strace -f -e trace=process -p 6913
[sudo] password for t: 
Process 6913 attached
clone(Process 12918 attached
child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7f457c05ca10) = 12918
[pid  6913] wait4(-1,  <unfinished ...>
[pid 12918] execve("/bin/date", ["date"], [/* 66 vars */]) = 0
[pid 12918] arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7ff00c632740) = 0
[pid 12918] exit_group(0)               = ?
[pid 12918] +++ exited with 0 +++
<... wait4 resumed> [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], WSTOPPED|WCONTINUED, NULL) = 12918
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=12918, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
wait4(-1, 0x7ffea6781518, WNOHANG|WSTOPPED|WCONTINUED, NULL) = -1 ECHILD (No child processes)
```

So the first two questions above are now answered. I am still not sure about the third question.

Comment: Does your shell have a `$PROMPT_COMMAND` or `$PS1` variable that  contains a `sed` command?

Comment: the first variable does. See my edit at the end. (I have added some setting (forgot where) to shorten the current directory appearing before each prompt in bash, is it the reason for `execve()` `sed` here?)

Comment: How did you think of `PROMPT_COMMAND` and `PS1`?

Comment: There are 4 ways that I know of for the shell to execute commands that differ from what you type: an alias, the `DEBUG` trap, the `PSn` variables, and the `PROMPT_COMMAND` variable. The `sed` command looks like something one use to customize the prompt.

Comment: @Mark: What is the output of tracing without my prompt setting? My other posts linking this post are not about the prompt setting, but about how a command is run in background, in `bash -c`, and directly in bash shell in terms of `execve()` and `clone()`. The part of output for my prompt setting makes others think my posts are duplicates of this one, while they aren't.

Comment: You can type `unset PROMPT_COMMAND` to test this. I'd assume that running `date` after you did this would result in just one `clone`.

Comment: @Mark: Thanks. Yes, as you expected, though I am still not sure why, when we have that variable,  we need two sequential clones 9099 and 9100 to `execve()` `sed`, rather than just one clone 9099.

Answer (score 1):

```
clone(Process 9099 attached
child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7f457c05ca10) = 9099
[pid  9099] clone(Process 9100 attached
child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7f457c05ca10) = 9100
[pid  9099] wait4(-1,  <unfinished ...>
[pid  9100] execve("/bin/sed", ["sed", "s:\\([^/]\\)[^/]*/:\\1/:g"], [/* 66 vars */]) = 0
```

The two forks (on modern Linux systems, forks are done by using the `clone` system call) are due to bash evaluating your `PROMPT_COMMAND` variable, which you said is

```
pwd2=$(sed "s:\([^/]\)[^/]*/:\1/:g" <<<$PWD)
```

The forks are not directly related to the SIGCHLD signal previously received.

The [bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Controlling-the-Prompt.html) says:

> The value of the variable PROMPT_COMMAND is examined just before Bash prints each primary prompt. If PROMPT_COMMAND is set and has a non-null value, then the value is executed just as if it had been typed on the command line.

Internally, bash ultimately calls [parse_and_execute](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/builtins/evalstring.c#n190) to evaluate the contents of `PROMPT_COMMAND`. Bash tries to minimize the number of forks it needs to do. For simple statements such as `pwd2=$PWD`, no forks are needed. For more complex statements, one or more forks may be done.  In your case, `$( ... )` results in a fork, pid 9099, of the shell, which will then evaluate the command between parentheses. The call to the non-builtin utility `sed` results in another fork, pid 9100, followed by an execve of `/bin/sed`.

> What does sed do here?

It appears to chop off all but the first character of the name of each directory above the current working directory.