# Compare running a command directly and in background

Tags: bash, background-process, exec, fork, strace

In Ubuntu, I run `date` in an interactive bash shell whose pid is 6913, and at the same time, trace the bash shell from another interactive bash shell by `strace`.

By using tracing, I would like to understand how `date` is run directly (see [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/267280/674) for tracing output) and in background (see [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/267278/674) for tracing output):

When running `date`, the output of tracing the first shell 6913 in the second shell is :

```
$ sudo strace -f -e trace=process -p 6913
[sudo] password for t: 
Process 6913 attached
clone(Process 12918 attached
child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7f457c05ca10) = 12918
[pid  6913] wait4(-1,  <unfinished ...>
[pid 12918] execve("/bin/date", ["date"], [/* 66 vars */]) = 0
[pid 12918] arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7ff00c632740) = 0
[pid 12918] exit_group(0)               = ?
[pid 12918] +++ exited with 0 +++
<... wait4 resumed> [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], WSTOPPED|WCONTINUED, NULL) = 12918
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=12918, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
wait4(-1, 0x7ffea6781518, WNOHANG|WSTOPPED|WCONTINUED, NULL) = -1 ECHILD (No child processes)
```

When running `date &`, the output of tracing the first shell 6913 in the second shell is :

```
$ sudo strace -f -e trace=process -p 6913
Process 6913 attached
clone(Process 12931 attached
child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7f457c05ca10) = 12931
[pid 12931] execve("/bin/date", ["date"], [/* 66 vars */]) = 0
[pid 12931] arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7f530c5ee740) = 0
[pid 12931] exit_group(0)               = ?
[pid 12931] +++ exited with 0 +++
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=12931, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
wait4(-1, [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], WNOHANG|WSTOPPED|WCONTINUED, NULL) = 12931
wait4(-1, 0x7ffea6780718, WNOHANG|WSTOPPED|WCONTINUED, NULL) = -1 ECHILD (No child processes)
```

When running `echo $b &`, the output of tracing the first shell 6913 in the second shell is:

```
$ sudo strace -f -e trace=process -p 6913
Process 6913 attached
clone(Process 31319 attached
child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7f457c05ca10) = 31319
[pid 31319] exit_group(0)               = ?
[pid 31319] +++ exited with 0 +++
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=31319, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
wait4(-1, [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], WNOHANG|WSTOPPED|WCONTINUED, NULL) = 31319
wait4(-1, 0x7ffea6780718, WNOHANG|WSTOPPED|WCONTINUED, NULL) = -1 ECHILD (No child processes)
```

When running `{ date; } &`, the output of tracing the first shell 6913 in the second shell is:

```
$ sudo strace -f -e trace=process -p 6913
Process 6913 attached
clone(child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7f457c05ca10) = 31294
Process 31294 attached
[pid 31294] clone(Process 31295 attached
child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7f457c05ca10) = 31295
[pid 31294] wait4(-1,  <unfinished ...>
[pid 31295] execve("/bin/date", ["date"], [/* 67 vars */]) = 0
[pid 31295] arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7f78b7f0b740) = 0
[pid 31295] exit_group(0)               = ?
[pid 31295] +++ exited with 0 +++
[pid 31294] <... wait4 resumed> [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], 0, NULL) = 31295
[pid 31294] --- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=31295, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
[pid 31294] wait4(-1, 0x7ffea67811d8, WNOHANG, NULL) = -1 ECHILD (No child processes)
[pid 31294] exit_group(0)               = ?
[pid 31294] +++ exited with 0 +++
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=31294, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
wait4(-1, [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], WNOHANG|WSTOPPED|WCONTINUED, NULL) = 31294
wait4(-1, 0x7ffea6780718, WNOHANG|WSTOPPED|WCONTINUED, NULL) = -1 ECHILD (No child processes)
```

Questions:

1. As far as running the command `date` is concerned, directly running it and running it in background seem to do the same
   thing:

   When running the command directly, the original bash shell  6913
   `clone()` itself, and then its clone 12918 `execve()` the command.

   When running the command in background, the original bash shell 6913
   `clone()` itself, and then its clone 12931 `execve()` the command.

   Both calls `clone()` only once. What are the differences between them?
2. It doesn't matter the command is external or builtin, for example, running `date&` and running `echo $b &` both call `clone()` once. Why is such a difference?
3. Compare running `date &` and `{ date; } &`. The Bash Manual says
   braces don't create subshell. Why are their tracing outputs
   different:

   - in the tracing output of `date&`, there is only one clone (6913 `clone()` to create 12931) and the clone 12931 `execve()` `date`,
   - in the tracing output of `{ date; }&`, there are two clones (6913 `clone()` to create 31294, and 31294 `clone()` to create 31295) and
     the last clone 31295 `execve()` `date`
4. It is said that a command running in background (e.g. `date&`) can access a local
   variable in the parent shell, because it runs in a subshell of the
   parent shell, while a command running directly can't (e.g. `date`), because it doesn't run in a subshell of the parent shell. Can we
   explain the difference using the outputs of tracing?

   ```
   $ b=1
   $ { echo $b; } &
   [1] 31214
   1
   ```

   Here `b` is variable local to the parent shell, and not an environment variable. The subshell created by `&` copies `b` from the parent shell, so `b` is echoed with `1` the value from the parent shell. I created this example, from [another one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/261406/674) which uses command substitution instead of background, which both create a subshell to run a command.

Comment: I don't understand your "It is said that..." statement about the ability to access local variables. Can you provide a link to the place where this was said?

Comment: @Mark: See my edit